# Chromium browser is embedded in on the top of CFromView , OnMouseMove is not working?

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++, mfc, screenshot

Chrome browser is embedded in my application by using the CFromView as the base class. But when I click on browser no CFromView related events are triggers i.e OnMouseMove, OnLButtonUp events are not triggers. help me out in this.

Thank you.

Comment: You will have to subscribe to [browser events](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/Events_T_CefSharp_WinForms_ChromiumWebBrowser.htm).

Comment: How did you embedd Chrome?